# Bound on the determinant of a quadratic form restricted to a subspace

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lattices, quadratic-forms, geometry-of-numbers, euclidean-lattices

Let $Q\colon \mathbb{Z}^{n}\oplus\mathbb{Z}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real quadratic form, which we denote $Q(x,y)$, $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, $y\in\mathbb{Z}^m$. Suppose:

1. The minimum of $Q(x,y)$ as $y$ varies over the integer vectors with at most one $1$ entry and at most one $-1$ entry and the rest $0$ and as $x$ varies freely is one. Namely, $\min_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n, y\in A, (x,y)\neq(0,0)} Q(x,y) = 1$, where $A=(B\cup\{0\})-(B\cup\{0\})$ and $B$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{Z}^m$.
2. The minima of $Q$ on $\mathbb{Z}^n\times A$ determine $Q$. Namely, $\{Q':Q'(x,y)=1\text{ for all } x\in\mathbb{Z}^n,y\in A \text{ such that } Q(x,y)=1\} = \{Q\}$.

> **Question**: Is there an upper bound on the determinant of $Q_0:\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, the restriction of $Q$ to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (i.e., $Q_0(x) = Q(x,0)$) that depends only on $n$ and $m$?

Note that $Q$ need not be positive semidefinite. On the other hand $Q_0$ must be positive definite from the fact that $Q_0(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, as implied by (1). Hadamard's inequality gives a bound on the determinant of $Q$ from the fact that (2) gives (at least) a linearly independent set of $n+m$ integer vectors where $Q$ takes the value 1. But because of the possible indefiniteness of $Q$, I don't think that yields a bound on the determinant of $Q_0$.

Even a result for the simplest case $m=1$ would be helpful. Here we have simply $A=\{-1,0,1\}$. Are the conditions (1) and (2) enough to put an upper bound on the determinant of the upper-left block of $Q$?

UPDATE: This question came up in the course of writing [Locally optimal 2-periodic sphere packings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08156v1) with Alexei Andreanov, now on the arXiv. It is still unresolved. A positive answer would prove that our scheme for algorithmically enumerating all locally optimal 2-periodic sphere packings is guaranteed to halt in any dimension (see Section 2.4 in the preprint).